# How do you use a scope Tomcat DataSource with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, datasource, spring-batch

I am currently using Spring Batch to import data from a SQL server. In order to make the datasource configurable I needed to "step scope" the datasource bean. However, this concerns me. If the datasource bean, which does connection pooling, is step scoped, then how can it manage connection in a pool and is there even a benefit to using it.

My datasource is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSourceMssql" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" scope="step">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.mssql.driver}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.mssql.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.mssql.password}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="3610" />
    <property name="url"
        value="${batch.mssql.connect}#{jobParameters['dburl']}:#{jobParameters['port']}/#{jobParameters['databaseName']}" />
</bean>
```

Why is it step scoped? Because I needed to retrieve the jobParameters to configure the datasource.

**What do I want to know?** 
Will connection pooling still occur? (Perhaps the beans resources stay alive and are reclaimed)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why do you form your url from job parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope "step" is only usable on spring batch beans.  Other beans (Spring) only know the scope : singleton, prototype, request or session.

Normal way to handle this is to set these parameters in a properties file read by your applicatioonContext.xml.

JobParameters are used to pass Job related parameters (path, filename, date, seqNo etc) since a job with the same JobParameters won't be able to run twice.

EDIT: Is your job multithreaded?  Because majority of the jobs created are single threaded!  If your job is in fact single thread, i would ask myself why pooling connections is needed!

Regards

Comment: The "batch.mssql" are indeed properties.

The Job Parameters exist so that I can reuse the same module for different data sources. Note that I pass in the DB Name, port and URL.

My job is not multithreaded. To which you make a good point. If you have a suggestion as to a different datasource to use that does not use connection pooling, feel free to suggest. 

If I am not mistaken I switched to a more robust DataSource because the basic ones were not throwing a timeout connection error. However, since I have re-wrote the module this may no longer be an issue. I can always try it out.

Comment: Most of the time i use class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource".  I also used class="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource" for a DB2 i worked with.  Both run without any problems

Comment: It seems as though BasicDataSource also does connection pooling. My main problem is actually that the resources were not getting released back to the system. Sockets would stay open and eventually all ports would be claimed on Windows Server R2. I supposed I should have asked that question.... Will bean destruction release resources (On either datasource)?

Comment: I can see that your config miss the destroy-method="close" in the datasource definition.  This will close connections when your bean lifecycle ends.